Transformation of function square root and absolute value
Hey yesterday I asked in the forum question about limit with function that has square root, and I was shown I need to take out the x to become absolute value.
In this new example I was asked to find the max and min of the function, so I started with doing exactly as they answer me, but after I took out the x of the square root, It changed the domain, and I also not sure if the derivative remained the same.
I would be glad if someone could clarify the issue when should I take the x out of the square root, and why it's not working like the other discussion in the attachment.
The function I was give:
$ 
(x+2)\sqrt{4-x^2}
$
The simplification I tried to do before doing derivative, but got different domain:
$
(x+2)\sqrt{4-x^2} = (x+2)|x|\sqrt{(4/x^2) - 1}
$
Link to the question I asked about:
Limit of square root, not working as expected

The domains of $f(x):=(x+2)\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $h(x):=(x+2)|x|\sqrt{(4/x^2) - 1}$ are the same except that $h(0)$ is undefined. More precisely, $\operatorname{dom}(f)={x\in\Bbb R\mid4-x^2\ge0}=[-2,2]$, and $\operatorname{dom}(h)=[-2,0)\cup(0,2]$. But $h$ is not easier to study than $f$. Better study $f$ directly.

derivative, plot
